# Open flash chart not working

Tags: javascript, flash, open-flash-chart

I want to implement Open Flash Chart in my website but it doesn't work. The chart just start loading for a second and the loader animation disappear and nothing happening (Only a blank swf area). i've downloaded the latest version which is 2 and here is my folders scheme:

```
// ROOT //
● JS
● open-flash-chart
● php-ofc-library
- open-flash-chart.swf
- mydata.php
- mypage.html
```

This is `mydata.php` content:

```
{"elements":[{"type":"bar","values":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}],"title":{"text":"Wed Apr 21 2010"}}
```

This is `mypage.html` content:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.embedSWF("open-flash-chart.swf", "my_chart", "550", "200","9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf",  {"data-file":"mydata.php"}  );
</script>
<div id="my_chart"></div>
```

The `JS` folder contain swfobject and the `open-flash-chart` folder contain the action script classes of the chart

Is there any mistake i did?

Thanks

Comment: I do have same problem using java. Did u manage to fix it? Any clues on this? My chart loads but i get a blank chart. I have checked json and is well formatted.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure you're using OFC version 2? You can grab it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/openflashchart/files/.

Second, you should be calling the embedSWF after the  has been created.

Assuming you're doing #1 and you change #2, this will fix it.